# Press alt + numeric in bash and you get (arg [numeric]) what is that?

Tags: bash, shell, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

Press alt + numeric in bash and you get (arg [numeric]) what is that?

(This type of question is better suited for asking a human, instead of trying to "guess" for the correct terminology to search on the documentation via internet).

Comment: If you have `set keymap vi` in `~/.inputrc`, then hitting `Esc + Digit` leads you to the same mode, as if preparing for a vi command repetition (but you can't use vi bindings from them on, only ugly emacs ones :-()

Comment: My search phrases were *alt number terminal linux*, *alt + 1-9 terminal* and eventually *shell alt + 1* which brought me here.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The term you want to google for is:

```
"readline arguments"
```

This will lead to, for example, this [chapter from the bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Arguments):

> You can pass numeric arguments to Readline commands. Sometimes the argument acts as a **repeat count**, other times it is the sign of the argument that is significant. If you pass a negative argument to a command which normally acts in a forward direction, that command will act in a backward direction. For example, to kill text back to the start of the line, you might type 'M-- C-k'.
>
> The general way to pass numeric arguments to a command is to type meta digits before the command. If the first 'digit' typed is a minus sign ('-'), then the sign of the argument will be negative. Once you have typed one meta digit to get the argument started, you can type the remainder of the digits, and then the command. For example, to give the C-d command an argument of 10, you could type 'M-1 0 C-d', which will delete the next ten characters on the input line.

For that to work, you have to know where the Meta key is mapped: sometimes it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>, sometimes it's <kbd>Esc</kbd>, cool computers have a dedicated Meta key ;)

For those not familiar with the syntax, 'M-- C-k' is the equivalent of <kbd>Meta_key</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.  "M" is shorthand for the Meta key, which, as noted, varies by system, "C" is shorthand for the Ctrl key.  The "-" after a character (like "M-") is not something you type, it's a way of indicating simultaneous key presses.

Comment: Is there a way to repeat numeric characters using numeric arguments? For example, say I wanted to write 128 zeros ('0'), I would think I could write Alt+128 then 0, but that gives me `(arg: 1280` (even though I let go of the Alt key). How would I repeat numbers using this mechanism?

Comment: @Victor: interesting questions. i can't think of a way to do it with readline. you're probably better off with something like `$(perl -e 'print "0" x 128')`

Comment: @VictorZamanian see [another answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11572715/1789543)

Answer (score 42):

In order to repeat numeric characters - e.g. 128 zeroes, hit the following:

<kbd>Meta-key + 1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl + v</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>

Comment: Ohhhh, it's just like `vim` (maybe emacs as well, I can't remember).

Answer (score 18):

Try this.  Type <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd>, then type <kbd>T</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Edited to use the snazzier HTML.

Comment: What happens for you? I'm not getting anything.

Comment: Four `t` characters are inserted.

Comment: In my Bash version (4.4) there's no need to press ENTER.

Answer (score 12):

It repeats the next command given that many times, same as in Emacs. E.g. <kbd>M-1-0 C-p</kbd> moves back 10 history items. <kbd>M-4 C-h</kbd> backspaces four characters, <kbd>M-3 M-t</kbd> moves the previous word forward three times, and so on. Here I use <kbd>M-</kbd> meaning "meta" for the Alt key, as is the custom in Bash.

Answer (score 12):

I know this has already an accepted answer however I did find some [useful examples](http://blog.yjl.im/2012/02/using-digit-argument-in-bash-readline.html) that also demonstrate additional uses aside from simple repeating of characters. The digit arguments can apply to all sorts of things. For example the sequence "Alt+3, Escape, Backspace" will delete backwards 3 words.

Comment: This can also be used with arrow keys to move the cursor.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know but when you do alt + numeric and then you press a character, you'll get num caracters: (arg: 123) + a -> 123 times "a"

Comment: you don't know, yet you know? %-|

Answer (score 2):

[bash manual section](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Arguments) - basically a way of repeating readline commands, or reversing them.