# Unicode special characters not working on Mac OSX 10.11.5 bash terminal

Tags: python, unicode, terminal, special-characters

So I have been used for a very long time to typing special characters such as accented vowels and the quite common `ñ` in Spanish language when using bash on my Mac. Specifically, I used to write commit messages in Spanish via bash using these characters, no problem.

After upgrading my Mac to OS X El Capitan 10.11.5, I noticed that as soon as I type one of these characters, the prompt changes and does not display the typed character, for instance, pressing `ñ` changes my prompt from

```
host:directory username  $
```

to

```
(arg: 1)
```

instead of simply showing `ñ` on the screen. A similar thing happens with other accentuated characters and other special characters, except the index displayed next to `arg` changes.

While working on my MacBook Air with OSX Yosemite 10.10.5, these characters display without a problem on the command line, as I was used to.

Both computers have the same set of encodings set in Terminal>Preferences, so that shouldn't be the issue. Also, the output of `locale` on both computers is the same, namely

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

I thought the terminal would be the only affected area through this update. It really turned into a problem when running a python script that would run perfectly on my OSX 10.10.5 Mac, would exit with encoding errors on my 10.11.5 Mac, under the SAME version of Python (3.4.3).

Comment: I don't know Mac, but that `(arg: 1)` looks like your keystrokes have invoked a Bash [Readline argument](http://stackoverflow.com/a/562179/4014959)

Comment: In the Preferences > Profiles > Advanced tab, towards the bottom, there's a section 'International' and a drop-down box to the right of 'Text encoding'.  Does that say 'Unicode (UTF-8)'?  I'm unable to reproduce on a MacBook Pro (13") running El Capitan 10.11.5.  I was able to type 'Option-n' and then 'n' to generate 'ñ' without problems, in both shell and Firefox when typing this comment.  And the terminal generated bytes 0xC3 0xB1 which looks (at minimum) plausible.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In fact, they were both set to UTF-8. The issue was with the 'Set locale variables on startup' checkbox, as you can see in my answer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it sorted out. I compared my terminal profile settings on both my macs bit by bit. The only option in which they were different, was in fact under Preferences>Profiles>Advanced. The 'International' section has a checkbox for setting locale variables on startup. This was not checked on my non-working Mac, whereas it was checked on my working MacBook Air. Checking the box and restarting the Terminal did it for me. I am not quite sure what else is set on startup with this option, seeing locale variables were set to the same values on both computers even before I found the fix.

Everything now works like a charm, I can type special characters on my shell again but most importantly, my python scripts now run perfectly without any encoding issues.

Comment: My working environment has the 'set locale variables on startup' item checked too.